# IDA Hex-Rays Decompiler : Show strings instead of offset

Tags: decompilation, hexrays

How can i settings IDA show me string instead of offset_xxx?

[image]

Comment: could you please add a text dump of the screenshot as well as the disassembly listing of the highlighted locations?

Answer (score 9):

Go to the menu `Edit -> Plugins -> Hex-Rays Decompiler`. A window will appear with information about the Hex-Rays plugin. Click `Options` and you should see a dialog like this:

[image: hex rays options]

Click on `Analysis options` and uncheck `Print only constant string literals`:

[image: option]

I learned about this option from the great [Life In Hex](https://lifeinhex.com) blog, but I cannot find the post right now...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the prototype of the function licensed_to() so the 2nd argument is "const char *" and, also, have you made a string at the given offset? If not, go to the address in that offset and press 'a' (or Alt+A and then select "Unicode").

Comment: Not sure i did it right but... https://i.imgur.com/fO54LAi.png and https://i.imgur.com/EziDXAB.png

Comment: I think it's a char **, not a char *. If that's the case, IDA will not show the string (because no string is being passed but rather a pointer to a pointer).